# Display detail of hierarchical model item in QTableView

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, qt4, pyqt

I'm using **PyQt4**, and have created a hierarchical model based on `QAbstractItemModel`, which naturally forms a rigid hierarchy:

```
 - Study
  - Recording
   - Config
```

The `study` item is the root item of the model, and a `QTreeView` then displays a list of recording items under it, plus their nested config items.

I would like to display and edit extra meta information about individual configuration items in another widget, when they are selected in the `QTreeView`. Depending on the type of configuration item, the number of meta fields to be displayed will vary, and so I am attempting to show them in a `QTableView`.

The `QDataWidgetMapper` class appears to facilitate this type of functionality, but I have been unable to find any examples for widgets showing more than one field at a time (i.e. other than line edits, combo boxes, tick boxes, etc.). Proxy models again seem like another potential route, but I'm not sure how to display a subset of the model based on a selection by this means.

Anyone has a suggestion of how I can achieve my goal using the model/view framework?

Comment: [Qt Reference Documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/classes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually came up with a solution using several proxy models.

I added additional columns to the model, filtering out the first three containing information for display in the `QTreeView` using a subclass of `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

The selection model was then linked to a method setting a 'selected' attribute for each model item. One proxy model [inspired by this blog post](http://lynxline.com/jongling-qt-models/) first flattens the tree into a table-like model of the same order. Another proxy model then filters the rows based on the selection attribute, and another filters for non-empty columns from the expanded set mentioned above.

This results in a single-row* table with the desired meta information. To display it as a column an additional proxy model derived from `QAbstractProxyModel` is used to transpose the table by mapping rows to columns and vice versa.

<sub>*It's a single row because only one item is permitted to be selected at a given time.</sub>